# array.push() repeats same value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

This is an object I tried to create to manage a list, but somethings wrong somewhere, whenever I used the `list.addItem();` for the second or third time, all the values(array) in the `list.list;` changes to the finally added value(array).

```
var list = {
  list : [],
  eligible: function(item){
    var status = true;
    var dw = (item.w*item.h*item.l)/169;
    if(dw > item.m){
      status = true;
    }else{
      status = false;
    }
    return status;
  },
  addItem : function(item){
    if(this.eligible(item)){
      this.list.push(item);
      console.log(this.list);
      this.refresh();
      alertify.success('Item Added to List');
    }else{
      alertify.warning('Item not eligible for Freight Calculation');
    }
  },
  removeItem : function(item){
    if(this.inList(item)){
      var itemIndex = this.list.indexOf(item);
      if(itemIndex > -1){
        this.list.splice(itemIndex,1);
        alertify.success('Item Removed from List');
        this.refresh();
      }
    }else{
      alertify.error('Item NOT in List');
    }
  },
  inList: function(item){
    var bool = false;
    if (this.list.filter(function(e) { return e.id === item.id; }).length > 0) {
      bool = true;
    }else{
      bool = false;
    }
    return bool;
  },
  findItem: function (id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
      if (this.list[i].id === id) {
        return this.list[i];
      }
    }
  },
  refresh: function(){
    if(this.list.length > 0){
      $('.items .table tbody').empty();
      var itemNo = 0;
      $.each( this.list, function( key, item ) {
        $('.items .table tbody').append('</tr><tr><td>' + ++itemNo + '</td><td>' + item.qty + '</td><td>' + item.m + '</td><td>' + item.h + '</td><td>' + item.w + '</td><td>' + item.l + '</td><td><button data-item=\"' + item.id + '\" class=\"btn btn-remove btn-block\"><i class=\"far fa-minus-square\"></i></button></td><td>Price</td></tr>')
      });
    }else{
      $('.items .table tbody').html('<tr><td colspan=\"8\" style=\"text-align:center;\"> No Items Added.</td></tr>')
    }
  }
};
```

I can't find whats wrong, maybe it's because I've been trying this all day. Btw I'm new to programming.

**UPDATE:** This is how i call the addItem:

```
    var id=0; //just for reference     
    $('.btn-add-item').click(function(){
        var item = [];
        item.id = ++id;
        item.qty = parseInt($('input[name=qty]').val());
        item.m = parseFloat($('input[name=weight]').val()).toFixed(3);
        item.w = parseFloat($('input[name=width]').val()).toFixed(2);
        item.h = parseFloat($('input[name=height]').val()).toFixed(2);
        item.l = parseFloat($('input[name=length]').val()).toFixed(2);
        item.country = $('#countrySelect').val();
        list.addItem(item);
    });
```

Comment: How do you call add item? And can we see the item object?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I updated the question with how i call the function.

Comment: Can you put it in jsfiddle and share the link?

Comment: @GijuGijja In case you aren't familiar with jsfiddle, here's an example for a jsfiddle for the code you have pasted thus far: https://jsfiddle.net/7fmcvy5q/11/ I haven't found any bugs. :/

Comment: thanks for the update - that is where your problem is! Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your click handler you are assigning each input element's value to the variable `item` as if `item` were an Object. Unfortunately, you've initialized `item` as an Array. You should initialize `item` as an Object. Then, your `list` Array will contain a `list` of Objects.

**Change**

```
var item = [];
```

**To**

```
var item = {};
```

Since you are new to programming, and Javascript is sort special in an odd way with this code, please let me explain why there was no error thrown to let you know this.

In JavaScript, Arrays are actually Objects. So assigning a value like you have (`item.blah`) actually places that property on the item Array Object as a property, but doesn't know your intent is to add the value to the list of Array elements. Javascript carries out what it believes is your intent.